# select option not reseting and not binding rightly through jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to bind one select option () as per this  select option ().
It is similar like binding Country and then as per country binding it's state's. 
Recently I am getting problem in binding **sGroup** properly. This select optionb during bind add extra empty . Beside this I am not getting how to reset this when selection is changed on MasterGroup.

**Here's my code**

```
$(function()
{
$('.MainGroupselect').change(function()
 {
  var id=$(".MainGroupselect").val();
  callsubgroup(id);
  });

  function callsubgroup(id)
  {
  $("#loading").css("display","block");
        $.ajax
        ({ 
          cache: false, 
          type: "POST", 
          url: 'User/asrs.aspx/GetSubGroup',
          data: '{id: ' + id + '}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: bindlist, 
          error: function (xhr){alert('Error occured');} 
        });
}

function bindlist(data)
{
           $("#sGroup").css("display","block");
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var subgroup = xml.find("SubGroup");
                subgroup.each(function () {
                var subgroup = $(this);
                 var option = $("#sGroup option").eq(0).clone(true); 
                       var vid=subgroup.find("SGroupID").text();
                       var vtitl=subgroup.find("SGroupTitle").text();
                        option='<option value='+vid+'>'+vtitl+'<option>';
                   $("#sGroup").append(option); 


                    }); 
  $("#loading").css("display","none");

}

});
```

**HTML Part**

```
<select name="MainGroupselect" id="MainGroupselect" class="MainGroupselect">
<option value="1">America</option>
<option value="1">China</option>
<option value="1">Europe</option>
<option value="1">India</option>
</select>
  <select name="sGroup" id="sGroup" style="display:none"></select>
```

Comment: This line can be removed: `$("#sGroup option").eq(0)` there is no option on the #sGroup by default (and add a var beore `option='..`) and you can remove old options with `$("#sGroup options").remove();`

Comment: Done, still no change displaying like this                       <select name="sGroup" id="sGroup" style="display: block;">      <option value="1">Male</option><option></option><option value="2">Female</option><option></option><option value="3">NotMale/NorFemale</option><option></option>          </select>

Comment: This is what you see in the browser? This is a working option adding sample: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/rmJJu/ (ignore some of the code, check the last 2 JS code line)

Comment: Can you post `data.d`

Comment: The last empty tag is most likely caused by the data...

Comment: Ya I know that ,It's simple to append option in select. But I am doing some silly mistake , I don't know what. I posted the code , please justify . Providing me example does't help's me.

Comment: data.d is simple xml getting from code behind. Containtg this value            ID:1, Title: Male , ID:2, Title :Female . I have checked it's not haing any blank value that is appending.